# Why do some women have menstruation-like spotting throughout their pregnancy?

Tags: human-biology, reproduction

An interesting question that was asked during a lecture about human reproduction: what is the biological mechanism behind some pregnant women getting monthly spotting that they mistake for a regular period? I've found articles and research papers about bleeding during zygote implantation, ectopic pregnancies and problems with the placement of the placenta, but nothing regarding menses-like bleeding during otherwise unproblematic pregnancies.

Comment: Related: [How common is it to be pregnant with periods?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/20033/6422)

Answer (score 3):

Here are some causes of bleeding during pregnancy:

- early pregnancy (first trimester):

  - implantation bleeding [1]
  - infection [1]
  - after intercourse [1]
  - miscarriage [2]
  - ectopic pregnancy [2]
  - cervical changes [3]
- second part of pregnancy:

  - abruptio placentae [1, 2]
  - placenta previa [1, 2]
  - miscarriage [2]
  - vasa previa [2]
  - preterm labour [1]

---

References:

1. American Pregnancy Association. *Bleeding During Pregnancy.* Available from http://americanpregnancy.org/pregnancycomplications/bleedingduringpreg.html (accessed 29.07.2014)
2. U.S. National Library of Medicine. A.D.A.M. Medical Encyclopedia. *Vaginal bleeding in pregnancy.* Available from http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMH0003748/ (accessed 29.07.2014)
3. WebMD, LLC. *Bleeding During Pregnancy.* Available from http://www.webmd.com/baby/guide/bleeding-during-pregnancy (accessed 29.07.2014)